# Implement support for Restangulars .several() method in ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, restangular

I recently found the handy method [`.several()`](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#creating-main-restangular-object) in Restangular.
Which allows me to fetch multiple single objects, very nice.

So I tried it out the following `Restangular.several('accounts', 'a', 'b', 'c');` which generates this url: `/api/accounts/a,b,c`

Which doesn't sit very well with my ASP.NET Web Api controller.
First draft:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAll() { ... }
    public HttpResponseMessage GetSingle(string id) { ... }
    public HttpResponseMessage GetMultiple(IEnumerable<string> ids) { ... }
}
```

This would be the ideal controller from my perspective. However it fails with an exception saying that MVC can't distinguish between the actinos :(

Second draft:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAll() { ... }
    public HttpResponseMessage GetSingle(string id) { ... }
}
```

Now this doesn't crash. But `id` is `a,b,c`.

Do I really need to manually `split` the string and work with it from there?
Also this wont work for `int` types. `public HttpResponseMessage GetSingle(int id) { ... }`

What is the proper way to implement `.several()` support in ASP.NET Web Api? I assume it's a standard REST call since it's in Restangular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute Routing with regex constraints can work here...

```
[Route("api/my")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAll() {
    // ...
}

[Route("api/my/{id:regex(^[^,]+$)}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetSingle(string id)
{
    // ...
}

[Route("api/my/{ids:regex(,)}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetMultiple(string ids)
{
    // strings
    var idList = ids.Split(',');

    //// ints
    // var idList = ids.Split(',').Select(i => Convert.ToInt32(i)).ToList();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Haven't really looked at the Route attribute yet, perhaps I should - thanks :) BTW you can cast like so `ids.Split(',').Cast<int>()` shorter and more versatile :)